# UCMA Steps to create Trusted Application

Tags: ucma, lync-2013, lync-server-2010, ucma2.0

What are the steps to create a trusted server application and then deploying it on the lync server?
I am new to lync server application development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally got thorught the problem, 
[This can be helpful.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh347354(v=office.14).aspx)

But in simple terms,
**Step 1 :** Create an Applicationpool by using Powershell Cmd [New-CsTrustedApplicationPool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg425804.aspx) 
<>Syntax: New-CsTrustedApplicationPool -Identity -Registrar -Site -ComputerFqdn -RequiresReplication
*-Identity :* this should be unique like MyApplicationPool.mycomputer.fqdn
*-Registrar :* can get it by using Powershell Cmd Get-CsService -Registrar
*-Site :* can get it by using Powershell Cmd Get-CsSite
*-ComputerFqdn :* fully qualified computer name
*-RequiresReplication:* this can either be $True or $False

**Step 2:** Run Cmd : Enable-CsTopology, this will enable your application pool, now you can verify it by running the command Get-CsTrustedApplicationPool.

**Step 3:** Create a trusted application by using the Cmd [New-CsTrustedApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398259.aspx)

Syntax : New-CsTrustedApplication -ApplicationId - TrustedApplicationPoolFqdn - Port
*-ApplicationId  :* Unique Application Id with Fqdn
*-TrustedApplicationPoolFqdn  :* -Identity parameter which we gave while creating the trusted application pool
*-Port :* Unique to your application, can be used in manual provisioning, used as a method parameter

Now follow Step 2.

**Step 4:** Create a Trusted Application Endpoint if required by you, using Cmd [New-CsTrustedApplicationEndpoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398594.aspx)

Syntax : New-CsTrustedApplicationEndpoint -ApplicationId -TrustedApplicationPoolFqdn -SipAddress -DisplayName
*-ApplicationId :* -Identity parameter which we gave while creating the trusted application
*-TrustedApplicationPoolFqdn :* -Identity parameter which we gave while creating the trusted application pool
*-SipAddress :* sip:user@host which is unique for your application endpoint
*-DisplayName :* Display Name like "Help Desk Contact"

Now follow Step 2.

In this way, you have now Created a new trusted Applicationpool, trusted server application, trusted application endpoint

Answer (score -2):

1: Download [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35463)
2: Read the documentation

Comment: Maybe the question is not so hot but this answer is terrible. The documentation misses the mark in several ways and figuring out just how to use SDK is not a basic (or even intermediate) task.

Comment: Maybe, but it is a good starting point to get the breadth of knowledge you need before diving in - the OP stated they were new to Lync server app development, so the SDK docs are the logical starting point. If you know of better resources to bring a beginner from 0-60, then feel free to post them here to help anyone else who comes across this question