# How to setup a development environment for UCMA Lync bot?

Tags: c#, .net, lync, ucma, lync-2010

I have to create a Lync 2010 bot. The initial idea that I pitched for the development purposes was to create the application on my own laptop and add the application as a trusted application endpoint to the production lync server. In that way I can develop and test the bot on my machine.

But, this idea was not highly encouraged by Microsoft themselves and they recommended to create a development lab environment to develop the application. I have done my fair share of research and have come to conclusion of adding 2 VMs -

1) 1st VM will serve as the AD server. My question is, what all things/roles should be added to this server like DHCP, DNS, IIS etc.?

2) 2nd will be Lync Server. Here I will create the connection with the AD server. Again, how will the connection be done? What extra roles should this server fulfill?

3) My laptop will act as the application server and I will add my laptop and the application as an application endpoint to the Lync server. Can I create all the three things on a single VM and not worry about multiple VMs?

4) Do I need an exchange server? If yes then why?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is really a server fault question and I would expect most programmers would not know the answer.  The above requires it's own network so yes DHCP and DNS are required.  Exchange server is no required unless you need voicemail.  Did you know that you can run multiple lync servers in the same lync topology?  So you can have a server for production and another for QA / Development.  That's what we do at work here.  I can't help with the server install as the admin guy does it here not me.

Comment: Thanks. It seems we already have an AD server and a test Lync server in place. I have an understanding gap:- Now I have 3 servers, 1 ADDS server, 1 Lync Server and 1 Application Server. I have to create an application pool in the Application server and create an application endpoint and the replication must be set to true so that the local management store copies from the central management store. But how does the lync server know, that it has to connect to my application server when a request for my application AD object comes. How is the ultimate connection happening between the 3 servers?

Comment: Put the question in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959187/setting-up-development-environment-for-ucma-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up development environment for UCMA Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959187/setting-up-development-environment-for-ucma-application)