# Setting up development environment for UCMA Application

Tags: c#, .net, lync, ucma, lync-2010

I have to create a Lync bot using UCMA. I have been facing a lot of challenges in just setting up a development environment, forget the actual coding. Before I put my question, I want to be clear that I am not a server/admin guy and my expertise lies on the programming and development side more than servers.

But, I have been tasked to setup all the servers for the Lync bot development process and finally develop and test the same. After a lot of research and big help from some members of this community, I have finally come to what I would like to call a starting point.

My question is:-

I have a test domain where a Lync server is already installed in a VM. There is another VM where an ADDS server is installed. Now, as per my understanding, I have to create an application server. I will set the replication property to true and replicate the settings of the central management store into the local management store. I will create an application pool and an application endpoint for my application in the **Application Server** . Now the question is:-

**I create the application endpoint and the application pool in the application server. But where and how am I connecting the 3 servers? I don't see a connection between my application server and the Lync Server or the ADDS server. I have not yet set up the application server. I am asking this question to clear my doubt before I jump on it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, as per my understanding, I have to create an application server. I will set the replication property to true and replicate the settings of the central management store into the local management store.

Unless you want to create a auto provisioning UCMA application, you DO NOT want to set replication property to true.  If you set it to true, each server in the pool HAS to there all the time so that the Lync topology can sync correctly without errors.

I would suggest always setting replication property to false, and it will make your life a lot easier.

If you do set it to true, then you need to install the Lync server replication software (takes awhile).

> I will create an application pool and an application endpoint for my application in the Application Server .

Make your life easier and create a single-computer application pool without replication.

> I create the application endpoint and the application pool in the application server. But where and how am I connecting the 3 servers? I don't see a connection between my application server and the Lync Server or the ADDS server.

The application pool is created under a FE pool of a (-Registrar).

When you create a trusted application, you have to say what pool it's running on (-TrustedApplicationPoolFqdn).

So the pool ties it to a FE pool registrar and the trusted application ties it to only being allowed to run on the application pool servers.

Lync server verifies that you are running on the pool by the certificates that you provide as part of your UCMA setup data.  Also the FE servers will also connect back to your applications on the "-port" and trusted application pool machine names.

I don't know what you mean by 'ADDS server'.  Do you mean the AD server?  There is no connection.  If it's anything else, I'm guessing no connection as well.

Comment: Yes by ADDS I meant AD server. For installing the Lync server we need to prepare the active directory right? This active directory will be the place where the application endpoint object would be added. My understanding is that, only when I create an application endpoint object in the AD then only the name of the application will appear in the Lync contact list. Correct me if I am wrong. Also, what I understand, I have to create the application pool in the application server. right?  Is there anything that needs to be done in the Lync server?

Comment: Yes there is a link between AD and the Lync server.  I don't know how to set that up but that's part of the Lync server setup.  Once that's done, you don't need to do anything with AD when creating / using application pools, or trusted application endpoints.  Lync does the AD stuff for you.  An application pool is a pool of application servers (or 1 server in the case of a single-computer application pool).  You either do it from the Lync server control panel https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg617964(v=ocs.15).aspx or the powershell commands like you asked about before).

Comment: So you create the application pool in the Lync server and not the application server. You add the application server( in this case a single computer ) to the lync server application pool. Is that so? Because, that is what I knew but a very bright mind in my office( sarcasm ) told me otherwise and that created the confusion. I was told to create the application pool in the application server where I have installed the UCMA SDK and Lync server core components through the local management store and not on the main separate Lync server which hosts the central management store and the actual Lync.

Comment: I think you are getting confused.  You create a "application pool" into the Lync Server.  There are two types of pools, single-computer and multi-computer. In the Lync Control Panel application the pools are under the folder title: "Trusted Application Servers" - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg617964(v=ocs.15).aspx

I would ignore the "Trusted Application Servers" title, it's just where the control panel displays the pools.

Comment: So a single-computer pool has only one computer in it and the pool name is the same as the computer name.  In the multi-computer pool setup requires a specific certificate to name all the computers in the pool and the DNS has to setup for the pool name to resolve to all computers in the pool.

Comment: Ya I confused it big time. Thanks. And does the AD server need to be able to perform the roles of IIS and Certificate Authority? Can I not use a certificate during development? I think any TLS communication requires certificates.

Comment: You need need a certificate authority setup and working correctly.  I don't know the details of the server side.  Not sure about IIS.  I think these are more questions for server fault not stack overflow.